# How can I access the virtual machine filesystem from within Windows?

Tags: installation

I've recently tried to get used with Oracle VirtualBox Manager and the QuickStart 1.0 VM machine: http://drupal.org/project/quickstart. I've installed it on

Everything looks fine and great but the only big issue is I cannot access the files from outside (Windows 7). I need to have a way to control the Drupal installs (backup them, commit/checkout with the linux server etc). How do I?

I heard there is a solution to install samba but this only works if you have a real linux installation on your computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the OS running the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create shared folders from Virtual Box Manager. For each drive you will have to create a shared folder. These shared folder will appear in guest OS as network file-systems.

As Ubuntu (Linux) is underlying in QuickStart.

Mounting temporarily need to fire this command from terminal:

```
sudo mount.vboxsf [share_name] [directory - mount point e.g. /mnt/share/]
```

OR

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf [share_name] [directory - mount point e.g. /mnt/share/]
```

Mounting permanently using fstab (/etc/fstab)
Make sure to install samba first (in ubuntu it should be already installed or do it `sudo apt-get install samba`, it needs internet connection)

Now edit your fstab file and add an entry in the last

```
\\vboxsvr\[share_name] [directory - mount point e.g. /mnt/share/] vboxsf rw,gid=100,uid=1000,auto 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I have internet connection in the VMBox, I will try it soon and let you know how the progress is going on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) for more advanced usage. [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) is also useful for mounting SFTP directories as Windows network drives.